# Исполнение Flask на Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, flask

Написал не большой сайт(одностраничный) и появилась проблема, после запуска Flask на ubuntu я получаю странное отображение файлов... Дело в том что первая загрузка сайта проходит со статусом 200, а последующие со статусом 304(стили и т.д.) и из-за этого вид сайта постоянно ломается, подскажите как с этим бороться?

[image: Там где статус 200 все нормально, потом идет статус 304 - тут как раз страница и не адекватная]

Comment: При этом, на локальном ПК все стабильно работает.

Comment: Этот код всего лишь означает, что файл не изменился, а в браузере уже есть закешированная версия файла, которую он получил раньше и браузер его использует. Это абсолютно нормальное поведение. Почему вы решили, что проблема в коде ответа 304? Что означает "постоянно ломается"? В чем проявляется эта поломка?

Comment: После нажатия на сайте Ctrl+F5 ЯБраузер, сайт открывается нормально код файлов 200, после простого обновления сайта код 304 и сайт отображается криво и есть ошибки по jquery.min.js и css

Comment: И ещё, после обычной перезагрузки есть ошибки во вкладке "Сеть"  (ошибка)net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE

Comment: но опять же, если перезапустить через ctrl+f5 то все нормально... пока не перезапущу обычной перезагрузкой страницы..

Comment: если перейти с браузера на css с ошибкой, то все нормально загружает.

Comment: А так же если включить галочку "Отключить кэш" то страница грузится нормально. Бывает, но редко (Отправлен недействительный ответ), а так норм.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот это решение мне помогло:

```
    @app.after_request
def add_header(r):
    """
    Add headers to both force latest IE rendering engine or Chrome Frame,
    and also to cache the rendered page for 10 minutes.
    """
    r.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    r.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
    r.headers["Expires"] = "0"
    return r
```